# How to reuse this C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can´t find a way to reuse the code below in all my webpages.

How can I do it?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        if (Page.Request.UrlReferrer == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("test.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

I´d like to use something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckURL();
}
```

Please, give me a example! :) I´m new using the C#!

Answer (score 4):

Just create a base page which all other pages inherit from.  Put your code in the base page.

so `public class CurrentPage : BasePage`  (inherits)

then

`public abstract class BasePage : System.Web.Ui.Page`

Comment: An extension method on the System.Web.UI.Page class would work as well.

Comment: Exactly what we do. If you like you can set the pageBaseType attribute of the < pages node in web.config for your new base page so you don't have to include it with the @Page directive on each of your pages.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new class that inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page` and add this piece of logic there and then use the new class for all your pages.

EDIT:

something like this

```
    public class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public MyPage()
        {
            Load += MyPage_Load;
        }

        void MyPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                if (Page.Request.UrlReferrer == null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("test.aspx");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and  add this in web.config

```
<system.web>
    <!-- ... -->
    <pages pageBaseType="MyNamespace.MyPage" />
    <!-- ... -->
</system.web>
```