# How to code reuse apsx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, design-patterns

I know in C# I can make a factory but I don't not know how to reuse code in aspx. My code was originally purposed for ARList only, but now has IcnList. I thought about making a switch statement but isn't there something better to code?

**The Function**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                ARExtractionController arController = new ARExtractionController();
                Dictionary<int, string> ARDictionary = arController.GetTickets();
                List<int> sortedARList = new List<int>();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kv in ARDictionary)
                {
                    sortedARList.Add(kv.Key);
                }
                sortedARList.Sort();
                sortedARList.Reverse();
                ARList.DataSource = sortedARList;
                ARList.DataBind();
                ARList.Items.Insert(0, " ");
                ARList.AutoPostBack = true;
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reuse this C# code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115926/how-to-reuse-this-c-sharp-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to inherit from a single page to reuse the code.

Top of aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MyNamespace.CommonCode" %>
```

Comment: What you say is technically correct, but I don't think it's likely to actually do what the OP really needs.

Comment: @tomfanning Technically correct.  The best kind of correct!  Oh wait, I see what you mean.

Comment: Unless you can have multiple Inherits attributes, of course! (which I'm 98% sure you can't)

Comment: @tomfanning Where were you nine hours ago.  We were going through the same thing, trying to reuse code in aspx files.  Ended up trying to embed ascx files in a dll before giving up and trying something else.

Comment: The answer here is surely just "create a class in the project" or "create an assembly with some classes in it and add a reference to it". There's nothing that special about an ASP.NET Web Application project...

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to be able to reuse the code, add a class to your project for utility methods and dump it in there for both pages to use.

If you're trying to reuse code with and associated UI, look into User Controls (ascx files) which allow you to do just that.

It isn't clear which is right for you from the question.

Answer (score 2):

In TicketExtractionWeb, create a BasePage class.

BasePage.cs:

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    // Add methods that are used on all your pages in here.

    protected DateTime GetCurrentDate()
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

And a page (we'll call it MyPage):

```
public class MyPage : BasePage
{
    protected Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentDate = this.GetCurrentDate();
    }
}
```

So when you create another aspx page, it will default to:

```
public class MyNewPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    // ...
}
```

Just change `: System.Web.UI.Page` to `: BasePage`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse html , please use a user control file (**.ascx**) , which can be reused muliple times

[when do you need .ascx files and how would you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217601/when-do-you-need-ascx-files-and-how-would-you-use-them)